# Enable Field level fallback for Final Renderings Field

Tags: content-editor, multilingual, language-fallback

I want to enable field level fallback for Layout->Final Renderings so when ever content editor creates a version in  new language he/she will get all the content from Fallback language.

But whats the best way to do this. Enabling field level fallback checkbox on `/sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Sections/Layout/Layout/__Final Renderings` item seems to be the only way. But this gets override on sitecore upgrade? Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's okay if you change that. Also don't see any other option. But it's only possible if you are on Sitecore 8.2 update 1 or higher regarding to the release notes.

https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/82/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2082%20Update1/Release%20Notes - reference number 105306

I found this information here - http://www.sitecorecoffee.com/2016/12/language-fallback-on-final-layout.html?m=1